# Visitor pattern and recursion

Tags: design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Is there any advantage for using visitor pattern in a recursive scenario? If so can you demonstrate it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about traversing a binary tree? e.g.

```
private class NodeVisitor{
 public void visit(VisitableNode<T> node){
    if (node!=null) {
       print node.data;
    }
 }
}



public class VisitableTree<T> {

  private VisitableNode<T> root;
  public void printNodes(){
    new NodeVisitor.visit(root);
  }

 private class VisitableNode<T> {
     T data;
     VisitableNode<T> left;
     VisitableNode<T> right; 
     public void visit(NodeVisitor<T> visitor){
       ..do something
       visitor.visit(left);
       visitor.visit(right);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this really recursive? I'm either missing something, or it is not. I think you want (in your VisitNode class) visitor.visit(this); and then you call this.visit(left) (and right). See [this link](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/binarytrees/).

Comment: Amending my last comment, it should be left.visit(visitor) (and right)

Comment: this code seems wrong to me. Shouldn't `NodeVisitor.visit` call `node.visit(this)`? And then `VisitableNode.visit` should call `left.visit(visitor)`, but that's just a layer of indirection.     Also, this answer doesn't actually show an advantage of the Visitor pattern

Answer (score 1):

I think the main benefit is that it only requires iterations over collections 1 level deep. It can call back, but at least the accept() method will be clean.